# Will Ada hashmap value of same key be overwritten

Tags: hashmap, ada

In Ada if I use the insert command with a key that already exists in a hashed map will it just update the value stored with that key?
Here is the Ada 2005 specification of the `Hashed_Maps` package:
http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18-5.html
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52472802/40851) is correct, but it does depend which `Insert` you use. There are several ([ARM A.18.4(44ff)](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-4.html#p44)); if you use [the simple one](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-4.html#p48)

```
procedure Insert (Container : in out Map;
                  Key       : in     Key_Type;
                  New_Item  : in     Element_Type);
```

then it

> inserts Key and New_Item into Container as per the five-parameter Insert, with the difference that **if a node with a key equivalent to Key is already in the map, then Constraint_Error is propagated**.

Answer (score 7):

When reading about the `Insert` procedures provided by [`Hashed_Maps`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-5.html), also refer to the documentation of subprograms common to all [`Maps`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-4.html). Note in particular the `out` parameter of type `Boolean`:

> If a match is found, `Inserted` is set to `False` and `Position` designates the element with the matching key. Otherwise, `Insert` allocates a new node, initializes it to `Key` and `New_Item`, and adds it to `Container`; `Inserted` is set to `True` and `Position` designates the newly-inserted node.

After `Insert`, an *existing* key/item pair will be unchanged, but you can `Replace` the corresponding key's item if required by your use case, e.g. to increment a count of times a particular key has been encountered.

In this related [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jumbleada), the procedure `Read_Dictionary` maps each dictionary word (key) to a word-set (item). In the loop, the procedure checks `Inserted` to determine if a new or existing set should be updated.

```
Word_Map.Insert(Sorted, Position, Inserted);
if Inserted then
   Set := new ACOS.Set;
   Word_Map.Replace_Element(Position, Set);
else
   Set := ACHM.Element(Position);
end if;
Set.Insert(Word);
```